# Using SQL column Alias in built-in function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, alias

I'm trying to order a selection based on the alias but I can't figure out how. Here is an example:

```
select distinct top 100 id, 
                    col1, 
                    col2, 
                    CASE WHEN @orderFormat = 'this' then col1
                         WHEN @orderFormat = 'that' then col2
                    END as orderby
from table
where col1 = like '%'
order by Len(orderby) asc, orderby asc
```

Whenever I pass my alias 'orderby' as an argument, it is reported as an invalid column.

My goal is to be able to order a variable column alphanumerically. I know that 'order by Len(orderby) asc, orderby asc works, but just not with an alias.

Anybody know a good way around this or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've managed to strip the select function down to this:

```
select top 200 Clip_Name as orderby
               from Clips
order by       Len(orderby) asc, orderby asc
```

Clip_Name is declared as `column Clip_Name(nvarchar, not null)`. The error from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Edition is `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'orderby'`.

However, this works (without the alias):

```
select top 200 Clip_Name 
               from Clips 
order by len(FLE_ID) desc, FLE_ID desc
```

Comment: does your versions of SQL support doing that?

Comment: Ordering should work fine. When you use `DISTINCT`, though, I think that the expression `LEN(orderby)` also has to be in the `SELECT` list. Are you sure you need `DISTINCT` here?

Comment: Also `col1 = like '%'` makes no sense. Even if it were just `like '%'` isn't this the same as `1=1` (or if col1 is nullable than `col1 IS NOT NULL`)?

Comment: @RandomUs1r I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I'm incredibly new to SQL so am still learning stuff. I'm bluffing my way through it at the moment to be honest. It seems strange that it's so difficult to order data alphanumerically though! EG. abc24, abc113, abc214 etc not abc113, abc214, abc24 as it would otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisPaton perhaps show the sample data and how you want it ordered, instead of just your bluffed statement and "not working." We might be able to show you a better way to do what you want, instead of just getting this specific, probably not-optimal statement working.

Comment: if it's MS SQL server, the alias should work just fine, look at your query though, your where clause is not correct syntax, seeing as it doesn't do anything logically, I'd just get rid of it.  This is also a good lesson on SSMS, it doesn't always give you the correct line where the error is, or what that error may be. Sometimes you need to take the code apart with comments to find out what it's actually complaining about.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The data in that column is alphanumeric string data of various types. EG. FDT-125, AV55, DSV-2399 etc, though it really could be anything of a string type. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @AaronBertrand So ideally I'd like to have the data ordered alphanumerically, not just either alphabetically, or numerically. So as I mentioned in my comment to RandomUs1r I'd be able to have ABC-3, ABC-12, ABC-244; not ABC-12, ABC-244, ABC-3, as it is without some special sorting method.

Comment: Can you please add sample data and desired order as part of your question, not in an unreadable comment. Also, please don't ever say that SQL Server "seems upset." If you're getting an error message, STATE THE ACTUAL ERROR MESSAGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you're first query, and following discussion that DISTINCT needs to be removed, this will work:

```
select top 100 id, 
        col1, 
        col2, 
        CASE WHEN @orderFormat = 'this' then col1
             WHEN @orderFormat = 'that' then col2
        END as orderby
from t
order by Len(CASE WHEN @orderFormat = 'this' then col1
                  WHEN @orderFormat = 'that' then col2
             END) asc, orderby asc
```

Comment: SPOT ON! Thanks toby. Legend. :)

Answer (score 5):

When you're using `DISTINCT`, you can only order by expressions that are actually in the `SELECT` list. You can't reference columns, aliases or expressions that aren't there. Here's one possible workaround, though it might actually be better to simply remove the `DISTINCT` (if you have two rows with the same `id` then there is something seriously wrong with either your schema or at least the name of that column).

```
select distinct top 100 id, 
                    col1, 
                    col2, 
                    CASE WHEN @orderFormat = 'this' then col1
                         WHEN @orderFormat = 'that' then col2
                    END as orderby,
    len(CASE WHEN @orderFormat = 'this' then col1
             WHEN @orderFormat = 'that' then col2
        END) AS ignore_this_column
from table
where col1 like '%'
order by ignore_this_column, orderby;
```

Expressed much simpler so you don't have to repeat the expression (and also without the unnecessary `DISTINCT`):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT id, col1, col2, 
    orderby = CASE @orderFormat
      WHEN 'this' THEN col1
      WHEN 'that' THEN col2
    END
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE col1 LIKE '%' -- necessary?
)
SELECT id, col1, col2
  FROM x
  ORDER BY LEN(orderby), orderby;
```

Comment: I've removed `DISTINCT` and included the ordering as you have done above, but it's still saying that I have an "Invalid column name 'orderby'" in the Len() function.

Comment: You can't apply `len` to `orderby`, because `orderby` is a calculated (or whatever the term is) column.

Comment: @AndriyM What does that mean?

Comment: Nevermind: [here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)